# How can i extract value from object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
---
- !ruby/object:Comment
  attributes:
    post_id: '5'
  changed_attributes: {}
  previously_changed: {}
  attributes_cache: {}
  marked_for_destruction: false
  destroyed: false
  readonly: false
  new_record: false
- !ruby/object:Comment
  attributes:
    post_id: '6'
  changed_attributes: {}
  previously_changed: {}
  attributes_cache: {}
  marked_for_destruction: false
  destroyed: false
  readonly: false
  new_record: false
- !ruby/object:Comment
  attributes:
    post_id: '3'
  changed_attributes: {}
  previously_changed: {}
  attributes_cache: {}
  marked_for_destruction: false
  destroyed: false
  readonly: false
  new_record: false
- !ruby/object:Comment
  attributes:
    post_id: '7'
  changed_attributes: {}
  previously_changed: {}
  attributes_cache: {}
  marked_for_destruction: false
  destroyed: false
  readonly: false
  new_record: false
- !ruby/object:Comment
  attributes:
    post_id: '1'
  changed_attributes: {}
  previously_changed: {}
  attributes_cache: {}
  marked_for_destruction: false
  destroyed: false
  readonly: false
  new_record: false
```

(http://pastebin.com/J1angM6d)

How can i get the value of `post_id` as array?
`@arr = [ 5,6,3,7,1 ]`
Now i want to get those posts with this `post_id`.
Is this correct ?
`@p = Post.where(:id=>@arr)`

Comment: Asking if this is correct is a question you can answer yourself by simply trying it. You tell us, does it work? Does it do what you want it to do? If you had tried it and it didn't work, then you have a much better question to hit people with. As Thilo also says, you need to start accepting answers before anyone's going to reply to your questions

Answer (score 0):

```
@p = Post.find(my_collection.map(&:post_id))
```